# Cannot connect to the MongoDB in ubuntu 18.04 GCP server

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04

I got this error when I trying to connect to the mongo shell on my ubuntu server which runs on the GCP compute engine instance. Can anybody help me to find out this issue?

```
    MongoDB shell version v4.0.24
    connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
    2021-05-24T08:55:56.026+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
    connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:356:17
    @(connect):2:6
    exception: connect failed
```

I've run this command to enable mongoDb

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

but the output be like
`Failed to enable unit: Unit file mongod.service does not exist.`

Then I checked the status of mongodb using `sudo systemctl status mongodb`

```
● mongodb.service - MongoDB Database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-05-24 07:10:48 UTC; 15min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 13985 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 13985 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
May 24 07:10:48 quirk-backend systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database.
May 24 07:10:48 quirk-backend systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
May 24 07:10:48 quirk-backend systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: looks like `mongod` is failing to start. most likely due to a messed up installation or file permission issue. i'd wipe the VM and re-install mongo server. try [these instructions](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/how-to-install-mongodb-server-on-windows-linux-4in). ගුඩ් ලක්!

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the mongodb completely from your server by using the below commands.

> sudo service mongod stop
>
> sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
>
> sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
>
> sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb

Then try installing it again. If you have any queries on installing mongodb refer to the [document](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

After installing if the issue still persists,
The problem may be that your system couldn't find mongod.service when you ran - ‘sudo service mongod status’.

You can fix this issue by running the below command

> sudo systemctl enable mongod
>
> sudo service mongod restart

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there are multiple databases. If I do uninstall those details might be lost.